# Is it possible/feasible to replace certain characters with <span>[character]</span> as they are typed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace

I'd like to have it so that whenever a user types a '#' into the search form, the '#' is styled a specific color.

I assume that the only way to do this would be to replace every instance of that character with a `<span class="colorHash"></span>` and to then apply the color to the class with css.

Is this possible? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Wouldn't this cause an issue once the data is sent..?

Comment: Ah, good point, hadn't thought of that. I guess I'd have to filter out the span when the form was submitted somehow. That will probably be my next question once i get this figured out!

Comment: Where does the user type? It's of course possible in a `contenteditable` area.

Comment: Not if you made the actual displayed data a dummy element that covered the real input element.

Comment: unless i mirrored the form or something

Comment: That can be done with jQuery keyUp function

Comment: yes exactly! but yea right now its in an input but i could replace that with a contenteditable if necessary

Comment: I can only say that you can use key up of jQuery and check what user enters and add a style.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'll look into this and see if i can figure it out

Comment: You could use _http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/_, set `#` as your word.

Comment: IMHO you can, but you don't want this *ever*. You should keep a model of your data and render it with spans when the data changes. Otherwise, you will dive into chaos and despair from undefined behaviors.

Comment: @Frederik.L can you elaborate? You're saying I should not do what specifically? Is there another way to accomplish my goal (adding color to '#') without breaking the Frederik rule?

Comment: Thanks @WashingtonGuedes i'll take a look

Comment: Maybe check out the prismjs library and study how it "tokenizes" characters for syntax highlighting. It's waaaay more in depth than what you're talking about but you could adapt its technique. I rewrote it in typescript the other day,which is the only reason it came to mind. I could tell you how to do it w / typescript / Angular in a flash, but my plain JS / jQuery knowledge is very lacking.

Comment: Without breaking Frederik rule, you could do something like [this pen](https://codepen.io/lonekorean/details/gaLEMR). Click the "Toggle Perspective" button to see it in action. However, it may be too much.

Comment: @thesowismine My advice was basically to avoid replacing the default behavior of the keyboard input events. The average user will report an issue if his inputs do nothing at the end, but he will rage if he cannot input in the first place (i.e. an edge case or something breaking your custom logic). Furthermore, my suggestion is to maintain a model of your user input, with or without the help of a framework. If the logic part fails, the inputs will at least work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to have an element that mimics a text input by looking as much like one as possible be placed over the actual input. This mimic would be updated every time the input changes, and include the color-changed hashes. It would have no pointer events, so clicking on it would allow the user to interact with the underlying real input.

[Here](https://codepen.io/Quelklef/pen/MvXdaZ) is a reference implementation. It is by no means perfect, and I do not recommend copying code from it.

Good things:

- Input data is stored unchanged in an `<input>` element, so works fine with forms.

Bad things:

- What is shown is not an actual `<input>` element, but a mimic. This causes there to be no cursor (bad), and may cause other issues. It means all styling on `input[type=text]` should be on the mimic, too.
- Slight input lag.

---

A slightly different way of doing this would be to have the mimic be invisible, *except* for the red hashes.

[Here](https://codepen.io/Quelklef/pen/YxvbQZ) is a reference implementation. It is by no means perfect, and I do not recommend copying code from it.

Good things:

- Removes lag on input
- Cursor is visible
- User sees the real input element (good in my book)

Bad things:

- Red color lags (mostly visible when using the jQuery version of the code)
- Likely much harder to maintain. The mimic must be positioned to pixel-perfection on top of the real input.

Since this seems to be closer to what you're looking for, I'll include the code for this version here...

This code is by no means perfect, and I do not recommend copying code from it.

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="data-input">
    <pre class="text-input-mimic" id="shown-data"></pre>
</div>
```

```css
#wrapper { position: relative; }
#shown-data {
    /* Stacked in top-left corner */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* Clicking and typing goes through to real input */
    pointer-events: none;
}
.text-input-mimic, input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 250px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Calibri !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
.text-input-mimic {
    /* Make invisible except for hashes */
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    /* Pixel-perfect adjustments */
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-left: 6px;
}
.colored { color: red !important; }
```

JS (jQ):

```
$('#data-input').on("change keyup paste", function() {
    let inp = $('#data-input').val();
    let modified = inp.replace(/#/g, '<span class="colored">#</span>');
    $('#shown-data').html(modified);
});
```

Alternatively, JS (plain):

```
real  = document.getElementById('data-input');
mimic = document.getElementById('shown-data');

real.addEventListener('input', function() {
    let inputVal = real.value;
    let modified = inputVal.replace(/#/g, '<span class="colored">#</span>');
    mimic.innerHTML = modified;
});
```

Comment: yes exactly! does this break the Frederik Rule (see comments above)? @Frederik.L

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes

Comment: No, the input and display are separate. Inputting values updates the display.  So, no, if I understand what Frederik means.

Comment: @thesowismine. It depends how you are submitting your form. Sometimes there are workarounds that works just fine to specific cases.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant! +1

Comment: @Quelklef any way to reduce the lag or is there no better than this? If not I probably wouldn't be able to do it as the lag would be too much for users.

Comment: @thesowismine I have an alternative sol'n, will edit post in a second...

Comment: @thesowismine Edited.